# Ajax form submit with file in Laravel 5

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to implement fileupload in laravel 5. But firstly want to send data, for example, simple string. 
My form:

```
    {!!Form::open(["url"=>"/photos", "method" => "post", "files"=>true, "onsubmit"=>"send();return false;"])!!}    
    {!!Form::text("title", null, ["class"=>"form-control"])!!}    
    {!!Form::submit("Send", ["class"=>"btn btn-primary", "id" => "submitForm"])!!}    
    {!!Form::close()!!}
```

My send function

```
function send() {
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({        url: "/photos",
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: formData,
                    processData: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(data) {                   
                    }
                });
}
```

My route:

```
Route::post("/photos", "PhotosController@store");
```

My store function

```
public function store()
{
    $data = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::all();
    return $data;
}
```

And I have an empty data! Via Formdata is nothing receiving, but if I change params from formData to {text: "Hola"}, so I see that in answer from server, but via text I cant upload photos in future. What am I doing wrong ? Why I receive empty formdata ? Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Since I got here with the same problem and found a solution I thought I'd post it here.

First of all you will have to use `var formData = $(this).serializeArray();` to get your form data, instead of `var formData = new FormData(this);`.

According to the documention Laravel will automatically return a HTTP response with 422 status code including a JSON representation of the validation errors.

full ajax call:

```
//#ajax-form is the id of your form.
$("#ajax-form").submit(function(e)
    {
        var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
        var formURL = $(this).attr("action");

        $.ajax(
            {
                url : formURL,
                type: "POST",
                data : postData,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data);
                    //data: return data from server
                },
                error: function(data)
                {
                    console.log(data.responseJSON);
                    //in the responseJSON you get the form validation back.
                }
            });
        e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
        e.unbind(); //unbind. to stop multiple form submit.
});
```

if you want to upload files through AJAX I suggest you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously).
Hope this helps!

Happy coding :-)